# More efficient method of adding images to Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am using this code (from an answer to a StackOverflow question):

```
function insertImage(barcodesObject) {

// Create a document.
var doc = DocumentApp.openById("DOCUMENT ID HERE");

Logger.log(JSON.stringify(barcodesObject))

for(var key in barcodesObject) {
    // Get the URL string within each Object property (property name is the barcode text, eg. "Testing" barcode is barcodeObjects.Testing)
    var URL = barcodesObject[key];

    // Retrieve an image from the web.
    var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);

    // Append the image to the first paragraph.
    doc.getChild(0).asParagraph().appendInlineImage(resp.getBlob());
   }
}
```

to insert barcode images into a separate Google Doc.

**My problem:** Each image iteration through the `for` loop takes about 1 second (3 images = 3 seconds to insert into Doc), meaning a batch of 50 images takes a minute to process!

Seems like theses are the two culprits, according to the Execution Transcript:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch([http://MyBarcodeGenerator]) [0.276 seconds]
Paragraph.appendInlineImage([Blob]) [0.836 seconds]
```

Note: I tried moving the DocumentApp.openById() in and out of the `for` loop, but it stayed the same time, so it seems irrelevant to the long processing times

**My Question:** Is there any way to "optimize" this process, so it takes less time to add the image?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wonder if the new PositionedImages would be faster?

Comment: I'll have to take a look into that, hadn't heard of it, thank you

Comment: Your blog showed up at the top of the search, interestingly enough :)

Comment: It seems to take the same amount of time (9.5 seconds for 10 images). However, the execution transcript shows each PositionedImages operation taking 0 seconds... which definitely does not add up to 9.5 seconds. Probably something Google will fix later?

Comment: ...or just one more miss in that feature's roll-out. Too bad it's not faster, though. I would have expected the UrlFetch to have been the long pole. Unfortunately, I think you're stuck with this for now - any performance improvement will have to come from Google.

Comment: Oh well, it's relatively manageable. Thank you for your help!